# If objects are the same

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to check if a json is 'valid', by valid I mean the same type: for example

```
{"name": "John Doe", "username": "jhndoe"}
```

and

```
{"name": "Jane Doe", "username": "jane12"}
```

would be the same, but

```
{"name": "Ann Onymouse", "username": "anon"}
```

and

```
{"name": true, "age": "24"}
```

wouldn't.

Comment: Use `Object.keys()` and compare

Comment: What rule are you following? The type of the value of `name`? Or the fact one has `username` but the other has `age`? Or...?

Comment: Why is `Ann Onymouse` not the same? I think we need more information about the rules.

Comment: @ExplosionPills OP indicating #1 & #2 are same...#3 & #4 are not

Comment: None of those examples are valid JSON (i.e. they are all the same because a parser would throw an exception trying to parse them)

Comment: Your question makes no sense... as all those objects are not valid (from syntax point of view) and 3rd object from your description should be valid... and if it's invalid, I have no idea what do you mean by "valid"

Comment: Turns out I forgot the quotes, woops. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare two objects to see if they have the same set of keys, you can do it like this:

```
if (JSON.stringify(Object.keys(yourFirstObject).sort()) == JSON.stringify(Object.keys(yourSecondObject).sort())){
    alert("Same set of keys!");
}
```

Note however, that the given JSON Object example in your question is invalid. If that was just a mistake, you can still use this code on valid JSON Objects.

**Example:**

```js
var obj1 = {"name": "John Doe", "username": "jhndoe"};
var obj2 = {"name": "Jane Doe", "username": "jane12"};

if (JSON.stringify(Object.keys(obj1).sort()) == JSON.stringify(Object.keys(obj2).sort())){
    console.log("Same set of keys!");
}
```

Comment: I started to write similar answer, but stopped on the third object that is invalid (thats what op says). So your answer to given question is not correct :-)

Comment: @FlashThunder The given example of a JSON Object in the question was invalid. This could have been a simple mistake made by OP which does not make my answer incorrect. I edited my answer to point that out.